# Magento 2 - Change the layout programatically in Controller

Tags: magento2, layout

I want to change default layout file programatically such that if a user is logged in, it will load 2-columns. Otherwise, it loads 1-column. How can do it in Magento 2?

Answer (score 5):

Just before the return statement you can add following line of code.

```
$resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);

$pageConfig = $resultPage->getConfig();

if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

   $pageConfig->setPageLayout('1column');

} else {

   $pageConfig->setPageLayout('2column');

}
```